# Issue with wp_handle_upload

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, uploads

I am trying to upload a zip file from Setting Page.
I have designed a setting page and in that I have a file upload functionality.
I am using setting API to do this.

My issue is: I know that maximum upload size is 8MB by default.
When I am trying to upload file less that 8MB, it is working fine.
But when any file more that 8MB is uploaded, I am redirected to `option.php` page.

I just want to handle this type of issue but I am unable to.
I have used `upload_size_limit` filter to increase the upload size but still not working. Upload size increased but unable to Upload file size more than 8MB.

I have used `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter to check the upload size before uploading but it, but again for less that 8MB file I am able to check not more than that.

I just want to handle that issue. I don't want it to stop in `option.php` page

```
if ( '' !== $_FILES['html_resources']['name'] ) {
    if ( 'application/zip' === $_FILES['html_resources']['type'] ) {
        $upload = $_FILES['html_resources'];
        $file   = wp_handle_upload( $upload, array( 'test_form' => false ) );
    } else {
        add_settings_error( 'rdn-error', '', 'Please provide zip file!!', 'error' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to change upload size limit two options have to be changed in php.ini configuration file - `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. These options cannot be changed at runtime so you will need to have access to php.ini in order to modify them. Example:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 22M
```